# Symfony 2 кодировка пароля

Tags: php, symfony2

Здравствуйте, делаю регистрацию пользователей. Поле пароля - согласно документации

```
    ...
    $plainPassword = $user->getPassword();
    $encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
    $encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $plainPassword);
    $user->setPassword($encoded);
   ...
```

К примеру, пароль 123456 - если распечатать `E9x659yx3WsmBJtSLV/fUZlQKDozTsDiijtLSb4pFAw6fzcfhwSyHi3quh7pOqnS9Hrz0WQah1b79O8cJQLX3Q==`

Все ок, записал хэш в БД.

Тепер время авторизации. Опять же, хочу использовать этот способ, получаю данные с формы, кодирую

```
$encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
$encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $plainPassword);//тот-же пароль - 123456
```

Потом сравниваю значение $encoded и значение из БД, и они не равны друг другу, incorrect user password. Пробовал разные варианты, но почему то при записи - один хэш, при проверке - другой хэш. При том, что и пароли и функция всегда одинаковые!

В чем может быть проблема ???

Comment: Выведите оба значения, посмотрите на них внимательней.

Comment: Нужно больше данных. Какой энкодер используется для данной сущности? Точно ли в `$user` лежит один и тот же экземпляр сущности? Разные пользователи с одним паролем будут иметь разный хэш из-за различия соли.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй

```
 $encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
 if (!$encoder->isPasswordValid($user, $password, null)) {
     throw new \Exception('Логин/Пароль не правильные');
 }
```

в версии 2.8 так работает